# Customize TypeScript compiler options per folder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have the following project structure (Angular CLI + [Fuse Theme](http://angular-material.fusetheme.com/apps/dashboards/project))

```
├─ src/
│   ├─ @fuse
│   ├─ app
│   ├─ assets
│   └─ environments
└─ tsconfig.json
```

Files in the `src/@fuse` folder is an external theme → not compatible with some of the current compiler options (essentially `--strict`) and not changeable!

Is there a way to compile the whole code at once (done via Angular CLI with `ng build` or `ng serve` pointing to only one `tsConfig`) applying different TS compiler options for the `src/@fuse` folder?

Answer (score 3):

Features like this have been asked for here (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8855) and here (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18540) and they were denied.  There is no official way to do what you ask.

The general recommendation is to separate the `@fuse` code into its own module.  There is some discussion in #8855 around how to roll your own solution by patching `CompilerHost` which may be helpful.